# camel OptaplannerComponent in osgi

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, optaplanner

I have camel running on karaf and I would like to use the `OptaplannerComponent` to ingest a problem from xml file and send the solution to a jms queue.

I am wondering how I can make `optaplanner` find my `domainmodel` and the `solverConfig.xml` in its `classloader`. Ideally, the model and the config should be installable as a bundle that can be easily swapped at runtime.

I see that `OptaPlannerEndpoint` loads the config like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getCamelContext().getApplicationContextClassLoader();
    solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(configuration.getConfigFile(), classLoader);
```

Is it possible to get my domainmodel into that classloader somehow?

Comment: If I recall correctly that's an integration test on the optaplanner-camel module of the camel repository. How does that integration test does it?

Comment: It seems like I am running into this issue:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/optaplanner-dev/3BK57Rm3QCE/SDdSDS52CoIJ
Has this ever been resolved?

Comment: Not that I know - no PR was ever submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-optaplanner/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/component/optaplanner/solverConfig.xml#L27). I presume if you put your domain objects and solver config into a jar and add that to your dependencies, it should work?